# Page problem in apalike (BiBTeX)

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

Can someone please tell me the problem?

My pages in bibliography should be in "(" and ")" - exampe: (71-83).

[image]

[image]

This is the content of the reference:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! There may be something wrong in the entry whose key is `DruckmanKam2011students`. Please post its contents. Please also indicate if you've somehow modified the file `apalike.bst` to have parentheses placed around the pages. (Surrounding the pages with parentheses isn't the default method of this bibliography style.)

Comment: I have added the content above.

Comment: I have also edited my .bst. I have added 
(1) "(" 
(2) * extra.label * ")" *

Comment: Have you tried changing `title` to `title={Students as Experimental Pariticipants: {A} {D}efense of the "{N}arrow {D}ata {B}ase"}` ?

Comment: Yes, I have. It change nothing. If I remove "* extra.label * ")" * from my .bst, bib works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your version of `apalike.bst` is called `myapalike.bst`. In the function `format.pages`, I suggest you replace the current two lines just below "pages multi.page.check" with

```
    { " (" pages n.dashify ")" * * }
    { " (" pages ")" * *  }
```

After saving the file `myapalike.bst`, either to the directory where your main tex file is located or to a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution (in which case you'll probably need to update the TeX filename database as well), start using it via `\bibliographystyle{myapalike}`.

Comment: Thank you, Mico.

My bibliography was right, but I would like to know if there was a way to remove the "harmless error message"? :-)

Comment: I do that in a moment.  When I run BibTex I still receive the message. My function look like this:

Comment: FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages empty$
    { "" }
    { pages multi.page.check
        { " (" pages n.dashify * ")" * * }
        { " (" pages * ")" * *  }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

Comment: Yes, I deleted these files - and run it again. I use "apalike.bst" but I have edited the .bst - so it should not be the problem.

Comment: @A.F. - I just noticed that you do *not* seem to have taken on board the updated code I posted yesterday. You definitely need to delete the `*` immediately before `")"`, on both lines.

Comment: Great. It was the problem. Thank you very much. :-) I can see you know a lot about editing in (apalike).bst - Can you maybe tell me how I can order first/last name, so the first name in references is last, first - and second, third author is first, last? If you can see my point.

Comment: @A.F. - I'm glad the immediate problem is fixed. May I suggest that you post your follow-up query (about changing the order of first and last names for second authors and beyond) as a new question? That way, it'll get far more visibility on this site and thus have a better chance of inviting answers by others. :-)

Comment: I'll make a new query in a moment. :-)